# JMeter - Boundary Extractor where right boundary is end of line

Tags: jmeter

I want to use [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) to extract **only values** from a string similar to property file:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

I want to find 1,2,3
but I can't use Right Boundary as empty or regular expression as (\s+) or \n to match end of line

Is there any option to get the values or is it a limitation of Boundary Extractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the Boundary Extractor as (surprise) you have to provide the **boundary** so it could do its job.

However it is pretty easy achievable using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the relevant regular expression would be as simple as `([0-9]+)` as it evidenced by [`RegExp Tester` mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)